# Headers of chapters and sections with no change in table of contents

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I am using the following fancyhdr package to operate with headers in my paper:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

If now I want to change the header in the chapter (the chapter names are too long) then I write `\chapter[chapter short name]{full name of chapter}` and the same with sections

but such formula gives me "chapter short name" in table of contents. How to change the headers with no changing the original names in table of contents?

Comment: You can use load `titlesec` with the `toctitles` option for that (possibly you might have to load `titleps` in the place of `fanyhdr` for headers and footers  – not tested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\chaptermark{...}` to set the header.

`\sectionmark` is trickier since it appears on the same page.  It is designed to show the first section, and since `\section` calls `\sectionmark`, the default name is the first section.  So I created `\mysection` which does not call `\sectionmark`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}[2][\empty]{\bgroup
  \let\sectionmark=\@gobble
  \edef\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\empty\temp\relax \edef\temp{#2}\fi
  \section[\temp]{#2}%
\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Short title]{Long title}
\chaptermark{Short header}

\lipsum[1-9]

\mysection[Short section title]{Long section title}
\sectionmark{Short section header}

\lipsum[10-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, that's it. \chaptermark (similarly \sectionmark) does not change the title in table of contents. Thank You very much!

Comment: Update: okay it works almost: the long section title is on the page where the section starts, despite sectionmark function...

Comment: Another solution is to run \sectionmark before \section.  If \section causes a pagebreak, stick a \par\pagebreak  or \needspace in front.

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) provides for ToC, header, and regular sectional commands through two optional arguments. For example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[title-in-toc][title-in-header]{main-title}
\section[title-in-toc-and-header]{main-title}
\subsection{main-title-in-toc-and-header}
\subsubsection[title-in-toc][title-in-header]{main-title}
...
```